# Copy data from one table to another- Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two tables namely PERSON and WIFE. I want to make WIFE's data available in PERSON table while keeping entries of WIFE maintained and at the same time adding some the values of PERSON against the data of wife.

**PERSON Table**

```
    PK   NAME      ADDRESS    IS_MARRIED
    1  John        ab city     Y        
    2  Varvatos    cd town     N
    3  Smith       ef town     Y
    4  Henry       gh city     Y
    5  Lynda       gh city     Y
```

**WIFE table**

```
    PK  PERSON_ID (FK)    NAME         
    1    1                 Alice
    2    3                 Rosy
    3    4                 Lynda
```

Now i want to copy data of WIFE table into PERSON table like this
**PERSON table**

```
   PK   NAME      ADDRESS    IS_MARRIED
   1  John        ab city     Y        
   2  Varvatos    cd town     N
   3  Smith       ef town     Y
   4  Henry       gh city     Y
   5  Lynda       gh city     Y
   6  Alice       ab city     Y
   7  Rosy        ef town     Y
```

As in the given example you might have noticed that ADDRESS of wife is same as of her spouse and same goes for IS_MARRIED column. Moreover, the PK is also not duplicated. How to go about this?
********Edited********
Another important factor is Lynda already exits in PERSON table, therefore, i certainly don't want to duplicate her entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare
newId number;
begin
select nvl(max(person.pk),0) + 1 into newId from person;
for x in (
    select w.Name, p.Address
    from wife w inner join Person p
    on w.Person_id = P.pk) loop
   insert into Person(pk, Name,Address,Is_Married) values (newId ,x.Name ,x.Address,'Y');
   newId := newId  +1;
end loop;
commit;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CTAS-create table table_name as select whatever you need from both tables. Simply write a join and add create table as... above the select keyword. If you prefer insert as in Gordon's example and your table is big then you may add an Append hint to your insert...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
insert into Person(Name, Address, Is_Married)
    select w.name, p.address, 'Y'
    from wife w left outer join
         Person p
         on w.Person_id = person.pk
```

Comment: I think it should `right outer join` and instead of `'Y'`, it should be `p.is_married` and also `case when w.name is null then p.name end`

Comment: @Gordon Linoff What about the primary key?

Comment: dont touch primary key, it is just for join.

Comment: @FredrickGauss Primary key is an issue as it has to be randomly generated and unique from both the table

Comment: you should use auto increment methods of oracle:http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/AutoNumber_and_Identity_columns

Comment: Given that wife.person_id is a foreign key, I see no reason for an outer join in any direction.

Comment: You are actually right, you have two tables and referencing columns to each other, why to fill the one with other so wife table will be redundant?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try the below code: This meet your requirment

```
declare PKId number;
begin
  select nvl(max(person.pk),0) + 1 into PKId 
  from person;

  for x in (select w.Name, p.Address
            from wife w 
            inner join Person p on w.Person_id = P.pk
           ) loop

     insert into Person(pk, Name,Address,Is_Married) 
     values (PKId ,x.Name ,x.Address,'Y');

     PKId := PKId  +1;
  end loop;
  commit;
end
```

Comment: Is there any differences between my last answer and yours?